# How to Compile all SCSS to CSS In different files in node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I have different SCSS files in my SCSS directory, then I want to compile them all in CSS directory but in different files, like grid.scss to grid.css,etc.

**Here is my Command:**

```
"watch:scss": "node-sass assets/scss assets/css/ -w",
```

but It's not working.

Comment: this might help https://medium.com/@brianhan/watch-compile-your-sass-with-npm-9ba2b878415b

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: It says the insert output files

Answer (score 1):

If the input is a directory the **--output flag** must also be supplied.
Edited command below should get your work done

```
"watch:scss": "node-sass assets/scss --output=assets/css/",
```